# TfidfTransformer.fit_transform( dataframe ) fails

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a TF/IDF transformer (maps sets of words into count vectors) based on a Pandas series, in the following code:

```
tf_idf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
return tf_idf_transformer.fit_transform( excerpts )
```

This fails with the following message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "I'm trying to work out, in general terms..."
```

Now, "excerpts" is a Pandas Series consisting of a bunch of text strings excerpted from StackOverflow posts, but when I look at the dtype of excerpts,
it says `object`.   So, I reason that the problem might be that *something* is inferring the type of that Series to be `float`.  So, I tried several ways to make the Series have dtype `str`:

1. I tried forcing the column types for the dataframe that includes "excerpts" to be `str`, but when I look at the dtype of the resulting Series, it's still `object`
2. I tried casting the entire dataframe that includes "excerpts" to dtypes `str` using Pandas.DataFrame.astype(), but the "excerpts" stubbornly have dtype `object`.

These may be red herrings; the real problem is with `fit_transform`.  Can anyone suggest some way whereby I can see which entries in "excerpts" are causing problems or, alternatively, simply ignore them (leaving out their contribution to the TF/IDF).

Comment: pass just a string after combining all values. Do not pass Series.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem.  I *thought* that `tf_idf_transformer.fit_transform` takes as the source argument an array-like of text strings.  Instead, I now understand that it takes an (n,2)-array of text strings / token counts.  The correct usage is more like:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
excerpts_token_counts = count_vect.fit_transform( excerpts)
tf_idf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
return tf_idf_transformer.fit_transform( excerpts_token_counts )
```

Sorry for my confusion (I should have looked at "Sample pipeline for text feature extraction and evaluation" in the `TfidfTransformer` documentation for sklearn).